# Which one is better for memory management in iOS when we using ARC or manual memory management?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

In iOS we are working with huge data using apps ARC makes crash.When we using ARC any delay in memory management than older manual memory management? Which one is more better ARC or manual memory management?

Answer (score 2):

ARC is better as it lets you concentrate on the "problem domain" (fancy talk for "the work we've been given") and not the tedious memory management.

Using MRR won't solve your crash issues.  Only a redesign of your solution will do that where you use some sort of file-backed storage to keep objects out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

I fully agree with trojanfoe's answer, but one addition: There is no run-time penalty when you use ARC. The compiler simply inserts `retain`, `autorelease`, and `release` messages for you at the right place.